# Blank regions on electron(node.js) window

Tags: css, node.js, electron

I've used Electron 1.6.11 with Node 8.4 to develop a desktop application.
this is how my main window normally looks like:
[image: normal view]

but sometimes some parts of window will overlays with blank regions for no apparent reason. like this:
[image: bugged view]

This blank regions will go away if i click one of buttons or resize the form, or anything that make it render again(i guss).
Also, this blank regions only appears on that left side of form.
Im using CSS grid to arrange my components, could it be because of that?

Any suggestion is appreciated